# change the length of derived column in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis, string-length, derived-column

I want to change the derived column's length in my SSIS package from 8 to 100
How can I do that?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: [so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18740679/ssis-derived-column-system-variable-length)

Answer (score 1):

To increase the length of a derived column or generally change the type, you need to explicitly cast it

Current

```
@[User::Inp_FileName]
```

Revised

```
(DT_WSTR, 100) @[User::Inp_FileName]
```

Cast the Variable Inp_FileName to a data type of unicode string, length 100.